# Dates on the x axis applying arima

Tags: python-3.x, datetime, matplotlib

I'm trying to replicate a code in my dataset making predictions with ARIMA, but I would like to put the dates on the x-axis and not the amount of the cases variable. I have already applied some steps and have not been successful:

Applying the command `plt.xlim([2014, 2020])` I get the following error:

```
Length of passed values is 6, index implies 12.
```

My dataset has the following form

```
       month case
year
2014    Jan  11
2014    Feb  39
2014    Mar  36
2014    Apr  75
2014    May  44
```

When applying ARIMA I get the following result on the graph

[image]

The code I'm using to generate the result is below

```
df = pd.read_csv('Dataset', sep= ";", index_col='year')

# Create Training and Test
train = df.case[:72]
test = df.case[72:]

# Build Model
# model = ARIMA(train, order=(3,2,1))  
model = ARIMA(train, order=(3, 1, 1))  
fitted = model.fit(disp=-1)  

# Forecast
fc, se, conf = fitted.forecast(12, alpha=0.05)  # 95% conf

# Make as pandas series
fc_series = pd.Series(fc, index=test.index)
lower_series = pd.Series(conf[:, 0], index=test.index)
upper_series = pd.Series(conf[:, 1], index=test.index)

# Plot
plt.figure(figsize=(12,5), dpi=100)

plt.plot(train, label='Train')

plt.plot(test, label='Actual')

plt.plot(fc_series, label='Prediction')

plt.fill_between(lower_series.index, lower_series, upper_series, 
                 color='k', alpha=.15)

plt.title('Prediction vs Actual')

plt.legend(loc='upper left', fontsize=8)

plt.show()
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: where did arima come from? how does this related to ggplot2?

Comment: `plt.xlim` didn't raise that error, and you're not providing date time values to the plot functions as x-values